# EventListener "Click" not working on mobile devices - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, click, addeventlistener, event-listener

Well I have a code like this:

```js
const bodyTag = document.querySelector("body");

if (bodyTag.classList.contains("index")) {
  //Variables
  const burgerDiv = document.querySelector(".burger");
  const menu = document.querySelector(".menu");
  const buttonMobile = document.querySelector(".button-mobile");
  const barMid = document.querySelector(".bar-mid");

  //Listeners
  burgerDiv.addEventListener("click", openMenu);
  burgerDiv.addEventListener("click", closeMenu);
  burgerDiv.addEventListener("touchstart", openMenu);
  burgerDiv.addEventListener("touchstart", closeMenu);

  //Functions

  function openMenu(e) {
    if (burgerDiv.classList.contains("you-can-open")) {
      burgerDiv.classList.remove("close-burger");
      barMid.classList.remove("close-mid");
      burgerDiv.classList.add("opened-burger");
      barMid.classList.add("opened-mid");
      menu.style.marginLeft = "0";
      buttonMobile.style.opacity = "0";
      burgerDiv.classList.remove("you-can-open");
      if (barMid.classList.contains("opened-mid")) {
        barMid.addEventListener("animationend", function () {
          burgerDiv.classList.add("you-can-close");
          burgerDiv.classList.remove("close-burger");
        });
      }
    }
  }

  function closeMenu(e) {
    if (burgerDiv.classList.contains("you-can-close")) {
      burgerDiv.classList.add("close-burger");
      barMid.classList.add("close-mid");
      burgerDiv.classList.remove("opened-burger");
      barMid.classList.remove("opened-mid");
      burgerDiv.classList.remove("you-can-close");
      menu.style.marginLeft = "-500px";
      buttonMobile.style.opacity = "1";
      if (barMid.classList.contains("close-mid")) {
        barMid.addEventListener("animationend", function () {
          burgerDiv.classList.add("you-can-open");
          burgerDiv.classList.remove("you-can-close");
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/*===========
  GERAL
===========*/

body {
  background-color: #373737;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

/*===========
  INDEX
===========*/
.index-body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main-wrap {
  width: 99.9vw;
  height: 99.8vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 100px 10px #181818;
}

/*CONTAINER*/
.main-container {
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #777777;
  border-radius: 30px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/*NAV DIV*/
.index-nav {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 30px;
  left: -50px;
  top: -15px;
}

/*NAV TEXT*/
.nav-item {
  color: #c2c2c2;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 320px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 25px;
  transition: color 0.5s ease;
}

.nav-item:hover {
  color: #373737;
}

/*MAIN TEXT DIV*/
.main-text {
  margin-left: 300px;
}

/*TEXT WRAP*/
.text-wrap {
  margin-top: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

/*GENESIS*/
.nebula-index {
  font-family: "Bebas Neue", sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 200px;
  margin: 0;
}

/*PORTFOLIO*/
.portfolio-index {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  bottom: 0;
  letter-spacing: 40px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

/*BUTTON*/
.button-talk {
  width: 30%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: #373737;
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #4a4a4a;
  transition: box-shadow 0.2s linear;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button-talk:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px #272727;
}

.button-text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 300%;
  margin: 10px;
}

/*==================
  INDEX - MOBILE
====================*/

/*BURGER*/
.burger {
  width: 20%;
  height: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.line {
  width: 55px;
  height: 3px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: black;
}

/*NEBULA TEXT*/
.nebula-mobile {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Bebas Neue";
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  top: -25px;
  font-size: 50px;
  z-index: 22;
}

/*MENU*/
.menu {
  margin-left: -500px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #373737;
  padding-left: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  transition: margin-left 1s ease-in-out;
}

.text-menu {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
.top-text {
  padding-top: 100px;
}

/*Button*/
.button-mobile {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: #373737;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
}

.text-button-mobile {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-size: 200%;
}

.ghost {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 890px) {
  .mobile {
    display: block;
  }
  .burger {
    display: flex;
  }

  .desktop {
    display: none;
  }
}

/*MOBILE INDEX ANIMATIONS*/
/*TO OPEN*/
.opened-burger {
  animation: openedBurger 0.5s linear forwards;
}

.opened-mid {
  animation: openedMid 1s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes openedBurger {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}

@keyframes openedMid {
  40% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    width: 55px;
  }

  80% {
    transform: rotate(-38deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(-35deg);
    width: 64px;
    color: white;
  }
}

/*TO CLOSE*/
.close-burger {
  animation: closedBurger 0.5s reverse;
}

.close-mid {
  animation: closedMid 1s reverse;
}

@keyframes closedBurger {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}

@keyframes closedMid {
  40% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    width: 55px;
  }

  80% {
    transform: rotate(-38deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(-38deg);
    width: 68px;
    color: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&family=Montserrat:wght@200&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>NEBULA</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body class="index">
    <div class="main-wrap">
      <div class="main-container">
        <div class="burger mobile ghost you-can-open">
          <div class="bar-top line"></div>
          <div class="bar-mid line"></div>
          <div class="bar-bot line"></div>
        </div>
        <h1 class="nebula-mobile mobile ghost">NEBULA</h1>
        <div class="menu mobile ghost">
          <a href="./photo.html"
            ><p class="text-menu top-text">PHOTOGRAPHY</p></a
          >
          <a href="./code.html"> <p class="text-menu">CODE</p></a>
          <a href="./job.html"> <p class="text-menu">JOBS</p> </a>
        </div>
        <button class="button-mobile mobile ghost">
          <p class="text-button-mobile">LET'S TALK</p>
        </button>

        <div class="index-nav desktop">
          <a href="./job.html"> <p class="nav-item">JOBS</p></a>
          <a href="./photo.html"> <p class="nav-item">PHOTOGRAPHY</p> </a>
          <a href="./code.html"> <p class="nav-item">CODE</p> </a>
        </div>
        <div class="main-text desktop">
          <div class="text-wrap">
            <h1 class="nebula-index">NEBULA</h1>
            <h2 class="portfolio-index">PORTFOLIO</h2>
          </div>
          <button class="button-talk">
            <p class="button-text">LET'S TALK</p>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

And this work's on the browser but when I open on my phone don't work.
I tried the "touchstart" but that don't work too.
Could anyone help me to understand how this code needs to be modified for mobile devices?
I use the live server of Vs Code and when I open this on IOS the function doesnt work
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you see an errors? The code provided will work on mobile devices

Comment: There are some nuances with Safari mobile and perhaps others. Check out this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event

Comment: @Kinglish Safari v7.x was released back in 2013... Currently we're at v15.x - hardly relevant and most likely OP is missing some more details in the question.

Comment: Please may you share a [mcve] the shows the issue? At the moment we cannot replicate the issue with the code provided.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Already edited, thank you for helping!

Comment: The updated example also works on iOS safari

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yeah you are right, but with this code doesn't work.  
The burger animation doesn't work, neither the menu appearing. And I don't know why. Everything looks ok to me, works on desktop but not on mobile.